# Keep rows of a pandas dataframe based on both row and column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a pandas dataframe that I want to clean.Here is an example:

| IDBILL | IDBUYER | BILL | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 768787 | 45 | 1897-07-24 |
| 001 | 768787 | 67 | 1897-07-24 |
| 001 | 768787 | 98 | 1897-07-24 |
| 002 | 768787 | 30 | 1897-07-24 |
| 002 | 768787 | 15 | 1897-07-24 |
| 002 | 768787 | 12 | 1897-07-24 |
| 005 | 786545 | 45 | 1897-08-19 |
| 008 | 657676 | 89 | 1989-09-23 |
| 009 | 657676 | 42 | 1989-09-23 |
| 010 | 657676 | 18 | 1989-09-23 |
| 012 | 657676 | 51 | 1990-03-10 |
| 016 | 892354 | 73 | 1990-03-10 |
| 018 | 892354 | 48 | 1765-02-14 |
| 020 | 892354 | 62 | 1765-02-14 |

I want to delete the highest bills(and keep the lowest when the bills are made on the same day, by the same IDBUYER, and whose bills IDs follow each other.
To get this:

| IDBILL | IDBUYER | BILL | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | 768787 | 30 | 1897-07-24 |
| 002 | 768787 | 15 | 1897-07-24 |
| 002 | 768787 | 12 | 1897-07-24 |
| 005 | 786545 | 45 | 1897-08-19 |
| 010 | 657676 | 18 | 1989-09-23 |
| 012 | 657676 | 51 | 1990-03-10 |
| 016 | 892354 | 73 | 1990-03-10 |
| 018 | 892354 | 48 | 1765-02-14 |
| 020 | 892354 | 62 | 1765-02-14 |

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is not removed last row?

Comment: Because 020 does not follow 018, to remove it, it should have been 019.

Comment: when you say "delete highest bills" do you mean aggregate by IDBILL and delete the higher amount? So if IDBILL 002 had 100 for each bill, it would have been deleted, and 001 would have stayed?

Comment: For example, for 001, you compare the lowest bill of the 3 with the lowest bill of the three 002. And if there had been 100 for each bill of 002, the three 002s would have been deleted, and the three 001s would have stayed.

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```
df = df.sort_values('BILL')
df.loc[df.assign(cc = df.groupby(['DATE','IDBUYER',df.groupby(['DATE','IDBUYER'])['IDBILL'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().gt(1).cumsum())]).cumcount(),cc2 = df.groupby(['DATE','IDBUYER','IDBILL']).transform('count'),floor = lambda x: ~(x['cc'].floordiv(x['cc2'],axis=0).astype(bool)))['floor']].sort_index()
```

or:

```
(df.loc[df.groupby(['DATE',df['IDBILL'].diff().gt(1).cumsum()])['BILL']
.rank('dense').eq(1)
.groupby([df['IDBILL'],df['IDBUYER']]).transform('any')])
```